# Is there any way to print unicode character like white smiley face into the log files using java program?

Tags: java, logging, unicode

Is there any way to print unicode character like white smiley face into the log files using Java program or using logging frameworks like log4J

Comment: Well, you probably can find a Unicode code point for the smiley face. If the log files support Unicode *and* the font of the log file viewer contains the smiley face you should be golden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write **[Unicode characters](http://unicodeemoticons.com/)** to log files.

Instantiate a `org.apache.log4j.Logger` object, set appropriate parameters(See the tested example below) and then either

```
logger.info("☺");
```

or

```
logger.info(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(0x263A)));
```

In the second case, we are using **[unicode code point](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9728)** of the unicode character.

### Example:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;

class ExecutionListener extends RunListener {

    private final Logger logger;

    /**
    * Constructor for class ExecutionListener.
    */
    public ExecutionListener() {
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(GenericTaskInterpreterTests.class);
        FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
        fileAppender.setName("FileLogger");
        fileAppender.setFile("path/to/log4j-application.log");
        fileAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}.%M] %m%n"));
        fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fileAppender.setAppend(true);
        fileAppender.activateOptions();

        LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(fileAppender);
    }

    /**
    * Called when all tests have finished
    */
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Number of testcases executed : " + result.getRunCount());
        logger.info("Number of testcases failed : " + result.getFailureCount());
        logger.info("☺"); // This gets written to the log file
        logger.info(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(0x263A))); // Same thing as above, smiley face gets written to log file.
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Be warned that some editors don't default to saving in UTF-8, and that some versioning systems (e.g. CVS if I'm not mistaken) don't default to it either. Better use a constant `char SMILEY_FACE = 0x263A` or a Java source code character escape.

Comment: Not sure about CVS, I tried viewing the log file in IntelliJIDEA, GEdit and Atom and it displayed the character correctly.

Comment: I'm not saying that it cannot go right. This is especially the case on Unix and Android systems that default to UTF-8. It's just that it can also go wrong, in which case your smile may disappear :P

Comment: I can follow the argumentation of Maarten: `logger.info(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(0x263A)));` is performing way more robust than `logger.info("☺");` in my testings. That's why I also recommend this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to make sure the files are written in a Unicode encoding that can represent those characters. That would be UTF-8 or UTF-16.

When viewing the log files, you need an editor that can read UTF-8/UTF-16, and that has the appropriate fonts to show those characters.

Comment: I tried with NotePad on Windows 7 when I saved the file containing the unicode character for white smiley face in UTF-8/UTF-16 it did not show me the actual white smiley face. But in CentOS Linux when I tried the same, when I opened the same file containing the smiley face in gEdit it has shown the correct smiley face. It looks like it depends the on the OS/Platform

Comment: @user2367202 It depends on the fonts installed. I think a newer version of Windows would have the emote fonts installed by default. I'm not Win7 myself too, so not sure.